# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I HAVE this query and error :

> error message :
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi =
>   lokasi_wisata.IDP' at line 3
>           select id_lw,judul_lw,left(deskripsi_lw,30)deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,
>   nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw from lokasi_wisata ORDER BY id_lw
>   ASC JOIN provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi =
>   lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi JOIN kabupaten as kabupaten ON
>   kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten where judul_lw like
>   '%%' limit 0, 10
>           Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/mtma/application/models/pagination_model.php
>           Line Number: 21

query :

```
 $sql = "select id_lw,judul_lw,left(deskripsi_lw,30)deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,
                nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw
                from lokasi_wisata ORDER BY id_lw ASC JOIN
                provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi JOIN
                kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten where judul_lw like '%$st%' limit " . $start . ", " . $limit  ;
```

Comment: Your order is wrong: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/select/

Comment: Put the ORDER BY at the end, just before LIMIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `order by` part is not located correctly. it belongs in the end, not before the join:

```
$sql = "select id_lw,judul_lw,left(deskripsi_lw,30)deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,
                nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw
                from lokasi_wisata JOIN
                provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi JOIN
                kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten where judul_lw like '%$st%' ORDER BY id_lw ASC limit " . $start . ", " . $limit  ;
```

Comment: its work.. how do u know .. how can i resolve it without u all ??

where should i learn that sql located correctly ?

Comment: Just google 'sql tutorial', you'll get quite a few good ones. this is a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

SQL statements have to be in a certain order.

1. SELECT
2. FROM table
3. JOIN tables
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. HAVING
7. ORDER BY
8. LIMIT

So your query needs to look like this:

```
$sql = "select id_lw,judul_lw,left(deskripsi_lw,30)deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,
            nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw
            from lokasi_wisata
            JOIN provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi
            JOIN kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten
            where judul_lw like '%$st%'
            ORDER BY id_lw ASC
            limit " . $start . ", " . $limit  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be you missing a common or the alias is not claer positione 
Any way you have the order clause in the wrong place

```
   "select id_lw,judul_lw, left(deskripsi_lw,30)deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,
                                               ^^ here ( or you are trying to buil an alias ?)
            nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw
            from lokasi_wisata 
            ORDER BY id_lw ASC 
            ^^  the order by should be at the end of the query non between from and join 
            JOIN provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi 
            JOIN kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten 
            where judul_lw like '%$st%' limit " . $start . ", " . $limit  ;



             "select id_lw,judul_lw,left(deskripsi_lw,30)deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,
            nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw
            from lokasi_wisata ORDER BY id_lw ASC JOIN
            provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi JOIN
            kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten where judul_lw like '%$st%' limit " . $start . ", " . $limit  ;
```

this way

```
         "select id_lw,judul_lw, left(deskripsi_lw,30) as deskripsi_lw,latitude_lw,longitude_lw,

            nama_p,nama_k,status_lw,gambar_lw
            from lokasi_wisata 
            JOIN provinsi as provinsi ON provinsi.IDProvinsi = lokasi_wisata.IDProvinsi 
            JOIN kabupaten as kabupaten ON kabupaten.IDKabupaten = lokasi_wisata.IDKabupaten 
            where judul_lw like '%$st%' 
            ORDER BY id_lw ASC 
            limit " . $start . ", " . $limit  ;
```